# Mechanic and electric power after imbalance in power system?

Tags: power, generator, electric-machine, power-grid

After a power imbalance (for example a generator disconnection) in the electric grid, generation and consumption are not equal. This causes a dynamic transient in generators described by the Swing equation.
I built two different scenarios just to show my doubts.
How does electrical and mechanical power of a generator vary? Are their behavior like the picture on the left or like the right one?

UPDATE

I tested that the behaviour is like the right one. Therefore i see that the electrical power torque (requested by loads) changes and is not imposed constant by the loads' nominal powers. The problem is that the loads are constant PQ in the simulation and the requested electrical power is absorbed by another generator without regulators inside (there are only 2 generators in the grid). So why the electric power in output of the generator changes if the loads are constant PQ? Is it due to the mechanical power which increases thanks to the action of the governor?

[image]

Comment: Generation & consumption are *always equal* (as long as you include distribution losses as 'consumption').

Comment: @brhans sorry you are right. I just want to know if the electric power of generators (which suddenly increases) increases too as soon the mechanical power increases too (second picture) or the electric power is kept constant as in the picture one